# Converting JSON From AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to obtain JSON from a URL, the JSON is parsed and is supposed to be converted into an NSData format which is then in turn put into an array. However it doesn't seem to be working. I think i'm being stupid because it worked previously but now-

```
-(void)loadFromServer{

        NSString *trendsURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/data.json"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:trendsURL];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                             JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                             success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json) {
                                                 self.results = [json valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
                                             } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                             }];

        [operation start];




        NSError *anError = nil;
        NSArray *parsedElements = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:elementsData
                                                                  options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                                    error:&anError];

        for (NSDictionary *aModuleDict in parsedElements){
            MosData *aMosModule = [[MosData alloc] initWithDictionary:aModuleDict];
            [elements addObject:aMosModule];
        }
    }
```

The data is displayed in a collection like view separately, there is no problem with this separate view as it works when I access data from a file rather than server.

```
-(void)loadFromDisk{
    NSString *pathString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *elementsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathString];

    NSError *anError = nil;
    NSArray *parsedElements = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:elementsData
                                                              options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                                error:&anError];

    for (NSDictionary *aModuleDict in parsedElements){
        MosData *aMosModule = [[MosData alloc] initWithDictionary:aModuleDict];
        [elements addObject:aMosModule];
    }
}
```

The JSON that is fetched is like so:

```
  {
    "imageLink": "http://link.com/image.jpg",
    "size": 1,
    "title": "Food"
  }
```

I gave it another go, and still it's not working. results is a declared NSArray.

```
-(void)loadFromServer{

    NSString *trendsURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url.com/data.json"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:trendsURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                         JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json) {
                                             NSLog(@"Custom Mosaic: %@", json);
                                            self.results = [json valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
                                         } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                         }];

    [operation start];



    for (NSDictionary *aModuleDict in self.results){
        MosData *aMosModule = [[MosData alloc] initWithDictionary:aModuleDict];
        [elements addObject:aMosModule];
    }
}
```

I think the issue might actually be this having played around a little, for some reason, it won't pick up the results of the data parsed in the AFNetworking operation.

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];

    if (self){
        elements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self loadFromServer];
    }

    return self;
}

//  WWDC 2012 proposed method
+ (CustomMosDatasource *)sharedInstance {
    static CustomMosDatasource *sharedInstance;
    if (sharedInstance == nil)
        sharedInstance = [CustomMosDatasource new];
    return sharedInstance;
}

#pragma mark - MosViewDatasourceProtocol

-(NSArray *)mosElements{
    NSArray *retVal = elements;
    return retVal;
}
```

The results of the log is just JSON:

```
Custom Mosaic: {
    data =     (
                {
            imageFilename = "http://distilleryimage6.instagram.com/9969123a6af311e2b6c722000a9d0edd_7.jpg";
            size = 1;
            title = "Title";
        },
```

Comment: 1) What does not work? Error messages? Expected and actual results? - 2) Where does `elementsData` come from? It is not set or initialized in your code. - 3) AFJSONRequestOperation works **asynchronously**!!

Comment: Sorry i've added a little more detail, the issue that is occurring is there is nothing displayed in the collection view. It's some form of parsing error, but I cannot work out what.

Comment: What is your actual code? it seems to me that you're missing the async approach of the requests. Try executing the ``for`` statement under the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                         JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json) {
                                             self.results = [json valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
                                             NSError *anError = nil;
                                             NSArray *parsedElements = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:elementsData
                                                                options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                                error:&anError];
    for (NSDictionary *aModuleDict in parsedElements){
        MosData *aMosModule = [[MosData alloc] initWithDictionary:aModuleDict];
        [elements addObject:aMosModule];
    }
                                         } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                         }];

    [operation start];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't seem to work either, i've given it another attempt as added above. But it really does not want to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your json don't seem to have keyPath "data", remove the valueForKeyPath:@"data", please paste the result of "NSLog(@"Custom Mosaic: %@", json)" in your question.
The operation is asynchronized. The success block is called after the request returns data. Please put code in the success block like this

```
-(void)loadFromServer{

    NSString *trendsURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url.com/data.json"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:trendsURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                         JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json) {
                                            NSLog(@"Custom Mosaic: %@", json);
                                            // your json doesn't have keyPath "data"
                                            self.results = json;
                                            // Codes moved into success block
                                            for (NSDictionary *aModuleDict in self.results){
                                                MosData *aMosModule = [[MosData alloc] initWithDictionary:aModuleDict];
                                                [elements addObject:aMosModule];
                                            }

                                         } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                         }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but that doesn't seem to work either, the JSON is fetched and parsed correctly as per AFNetorking, it's the for(NSDictionary... section that seems to be the issue.

Comment: What's the result of NSLog(@"Custom Mosaic: %@", json)

Comment: I've added it to the question itself.